# How to center a block of the lines while flushleft/flushright is applied

Tags: horizontal-alignment

Obviously the following does not do what I have described in the title.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{flushright}
\begin{center}
\vspace{1cm}
Here is the first line.\\
Second line.
\end{center}
\end{flushright}
\end{document}
```

In other words, I would like an output like this:

[image]

Comment: It's not very clear: you want a centred block, but each line inside the block has to be flushright?

Comment: @Bernard I updated the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `tabular` often addresses in frontmatter are set this way.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}


\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
Here is the first line.\\
Second line.
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\begin{flushright}
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
Here is the first line.\\
Second line.
\end{tabular}
\end{flushright}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

Maybe you expect a right aligned block of centred lines. If so, you could use [`varwidth`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/varwidth):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\begin{document}

\begin{flushright}
\begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}\centering
Here is the first line.\\
Second line.
\end{varwidth}
\end{flushright}
\end{document}
```

[image: Right aligned block of centred lines]

Comment: That's a bit of overkill: since you're specifying the line breaks, a `tabular` is easier.

Comment: @egreg: As long as you really have only manually specified line breaks and as long as it doesn't matter that every line is a group on its own and as long a you have not changed e.g. line stretching of tabular rows in the document preamble. Sometimes pretended overkill may become a prefered solution.

Comment: I didn't mean the solution is bad! To the contrary, I upvoted it.